# Makefile : How do I compile my .c functions in a temporary directory?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm creating my own `libc` library named `libft` and I'm currently doing the Makefile that will create the `libft.a` .

I understood that I'm compiling my `.c` functions into `.o` files and then archiving all the `.o` files in a single file named `libft.a`. Correct me if I'm wrong, I basically learnt Makefile this morning.

My current Makefile is working but it is creating all the `.o` files in my main directory, but **I want to compile them in a separate folder named** `obj` **for example, and that is not working.**

Here is my working code that is not compiling in a different folder :
`SRCB` are "bonus" functions for my school.

```
NAME = libft.a

SRCS =  ft_strlen.c \
    ft_strrchr.c \
    ft_atoi.c \
    ft_bzero.c \
    ft_calloc.c \
        ...

SRCB =  ft_lstadd_back.c \
    ft_lstadd_front.c \
    ft_lstclear.c \
    ft_lstdelone.c \
        ...

CC      = gcc
CFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
RM      = rm -rf
AR      = ar rcs

MKDIR       = mkdir
O           = obj/
ODIR        = $(MKDIR) $(O)

#Turning the .c into .o
OBJS        = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
OBJB        = $(SRCB:.c=.o)

#Creating 'libft.a' containing all the .o
$(NAME):    $(OBJS)
        $(AR) $(NAME) $(OBJS)

bonus:      $(OBJB)
        $(AR) $(NAME) $(OBJB)

all:        $(NAME)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJS) $(OBJB)

fclean:     clean
        $(RM) $(NAME)

re:     fclean $(NAME)
```

And I have tested a bunch of different things like creating an `obj` directory and move the `.o` in there :

```
NAME         = libft.a
AR           = ar rcs
MKDIR        = mkdir
O            = obj
ODIR         = $(MKDIR) $(O)
OBJS         = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
OBJB         = $(SRCB:.c=.o)

$(NAME):    $(OBJS)
            $(AR) $(NAME) $(OBJS) | $(ODIR) | mv *.o $(O)
```

I also tried to create a new folder THEN compile my functions in that folder but my makefile won't work doing this :

```
#Turning the .c into .o
MKDIR           = mkdir
O               = obj
ODIR            = $(MKDIR) $(O)

OBJS        = $(ODIR) | $(SRCS:.c=$(O).o)
OBJB        = $(ODIR) | $(SRCB:.c=$(O).o)
```

And the terminal is telling me : `make: *** No rule to make target 'mkdir', needed by 'libft.a'.  Stop.`

Any help is much appreciated, thank you !

Comment: You are a long way from where you want to be.  I don't even know what the syntax being used in the recipe is: are you trying to pipe the output of the `ar` command into the `mkdir` command?  That doesn't make sense.  Remember that a recipe is a _shell script_ so whatever you put into the recipe (once expanded) needs to be shell commands.  I recommend you search the web for things like "makefile put object files in different directory" or similar terms and you will find many, many, many suggestions.  If you can't get one to work, come back and show us what you have and how it fails.

Comment: Just to start you off: make will build the files you ask it to build.  Your rule says `$(NAME): $(OBJS)` so it will try to build `$(OBJS)`.  The `OBJS` variable is set as `$(SRCS:.c=.o)` which means it will have values like `ft_strlen.o ft_strrchr.o` etc.  That is very clearly not what you want, if you want to build objects like `obj/ft_strlen.o obj/ft_strrchr.o` etc.  So the very first step is to fix your `OBJS` variable so it contains the names of the files you want to build.  Once that's done, you'll have to explain to make how to build those files, since make's built-in rules don't know.